# Showing correct response in Postman but wrong response in Android app

Tags: php, android, json, codeigniter, postman

I have a Registration page in android where user enters his/her name, email, phone and password. When I register any new user from the app, the response I am getting is always `E/Json response: {"success":false,"msg":"User already Exists"}`even when the user does not exists. But when I hit the same query through Postman, I am getting proper response like

```
{
  "success": true,
  "msg": "Confirmation Link to activate your account has been sent to your email address",
  "data": {
    "studentId": 8
  }
}
```

If I register with new users through Postman I am getting correct response but from app it is always showing "User already Exists".

Here is my Register Activity :

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ServerRequests.Registereponse {

    private EditText password, phone, email;
    public static EditText name;
    ServerRequests serverRequests;
    JSONParser jsonParser;
    private Button registerButton;
    TextView alreadyMember;

    Editor editor;
    UserSession session;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        serverRequests = new ServerRequests(getApplicationContext());
        serverRequests.setRegistereponse(this);

        alreadyMember = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alreadyMember);

        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FName);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PhoneNum);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mail);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Reg", 0);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CharSequence temp_emailID = email.getText().toString();
                if (name.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    name.setError("Please enter your name");
                    name.requestFocus();

                } else if (phone.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    phone.setError("Please enter your phone number");
                    phone.requestFocus();

                } else if (!isValidEmail(temp_emailID)) {
                    email.setError("Please enter valid email");
                    email.requestFocus();

                } else if (password.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    password.setError("Please enter password");
                    password.requestFocus();

                } else {


                    try {
                        String Name = name.getText().toString();
                        String Email = email.getText().toString();
                        String Password = password.getText().toString();
                        String Phone = phone.getText().toString();

                        JSONObject obj = jsonParser.makeRegisterJson(Name, Email, Password, Long.parseLong(Phone));
                        Log.e("final Json", obj.toString());
                        serverRequests.register(obj);

                        editor.putString("name", Name);
                        editor.putString("email", Email);
                        editor.putString("password", Password);
                        editor.putString("phone", Phone);
                        editor.commit();
                        //    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registered Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }

                //   startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

            }
        });

        alreadyMember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void onRegsiterReposne(JSONObject object) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "hiii" + object.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(target)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my Server Request class :

```
public void setRegistereponse(Registereponse registereponse) {
        this.registereponse = registereponse;
    }

    private Registereponse registereponse;

    public interface Registereponse {
        void onRegsiterReposne(JSONObject object);
    }

    public void register(JSONObject jsonObject) {


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Services.REGISTER_URL, jsonObject,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.e("Json response", "" + response);
                            boolean b = response.getBoolean("success");

                            if (registereponse != null) {
                                registereponse.onRegsiterReposne(response);

                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Error ", "" + error);
                    }
                }
        );

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Here is my JSON Parser class :

```
public class JSONParser {

    //----------For Register

    public JSONObject makeRegisterJson(String name, String email, String password, long phone) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

        object.put("name", name);
        object.put("email", email);
        object.put("password", password);
        object.put("phone", phone);
        // if its in array------
       /*JSONObject finalObject=new JSONObject();
       finalObject.put("request",object);
       return finalObject;*/
        return object;
    }
```

Server Side : 
I have done coding in Php using codeigniter framework:

This is my controller method:

```
public function register_post()
    {
        $data['name']       = $this->post('name');
        $data['email']      = $this->post('email');
        $data['phone']      = $this->post('phone');
        $data['password']   = $this->post('password');





        if (isset($data['name']) && !empty($data['name']) && isset($data['email']) && !empty($data['email']) && isset($data['phone']) && !empty($data['phone']) && isset($data['password']) && !empty($data['password'])) 
        {

            $model_response=$this->api_model->register_user($data);


            if($model_response == "E101"){
                $data_result['success'] = false;
                $data_result['msg'] = "User already Exists";
            }   

            if($model_response == "E103" || $model_response == "E102"){
                $data_result['success'] = false;
                $data_result['msg'] = "Record Not Inserted";
            }
            else
                {
                    $name = $data['name'];
                    $emailid = $data['email'];
                    $link = "<a href=''>Verification Link</a>";
                    $mail = new PHPMailer;
                    $mail->isSMTP();
                    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
                    $mail->Host = "dash.dash.in";
                    $mail->Port = 25;
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                    $mail->isHTML(true);
                    $mail->Username = "dash@dash.in";
                    $mail->Password = "******";
                    $mail->setFrom('dash@dash.in','Training App');
                    $mail->addAddress($emailid, 'Registration');
                    $mail->Subject = 'Registration - Training App';
                    $mail->Body = "<p>Hi $name,<br/><br/>You are successfully registered with us.<br/><br/> Please Click below link to activate your account<br/> Link - $link<br/><br/>If you have any queries or encounter any problems in logging in, please contact us on :<br>dash@dash.com <br/><br/> Thank you.</p>";
                    if($mail->send()){

                        $data_result['success'] = true;
                        $data_result['msg'] = "Confirmation Link to activate your account has been sent to your email address";
                        $data_result['data'] = array('studentId' => $model_response);
                    }else{
                        $data_result['success'] = false;
                        $data_result["msg"] = "Failed to send mail.";
                    }
                }

        }
        else{
            $data_result['success'] = false;
            $data_result['msg'] = "Please Check Your Request";
        }
        $this->response($data_result);
    }
```

This is my model Code:

```
public function register_user($data)
        {
            $email = $data['email'];
            $this->db->select('username as email');
            $this->db->where('username',$email);
            $query = $this->db->get('tbl_login');

            if($query->row() > 0)
            {
                return "E101";
            }else{
                $data_l = array(
                'username'  => $data['email'], 
                'role'      => 2,
                'password'  => md5($data['password'])
                );
                $this->db->insert('tbl_login', $data_l);
                if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1) {
                    $loginId = $this->db->insert_id();
                    $data_s = array(
                    'name'  => $data['name'], 
                    'email' => $data['email'], 
                    'phone' => $data['phone'],
                    'loginId' => $loginId
                    );
                    $this->db->insert('student', $data_s);
                    if ($this->db->affected_rows() == 1) {
                        $studentId = $this->db->insert_id();
                        return $studentId;
                    } else {
                        return "E102";
                    }
                }else {
                    return "E103";
                }
            }
        }
```

I dont know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can you also paste the curl that is being fired from Postman?

Comment: @mobiledev curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: f8566f2b-8875-c1f8-5ce4-d4cb5654438a" -d '{"name":"Salman","email":"salmanshaikh6s5s75@gmail.com","password":"1234","phone":9637060561}' "http://thelocalhost/jostna/TrainingPortal/Mobile/register"

Comment: Please check my edited code. I have added server side code in PHP

Comment: try using $this->post_get while fetching data in function register_post() and check what happens @Sallu

Comment: Sorry for late response

Comment: If this doesn't helps try this, There's also a handy method to check both at the same time:

$this->input->get_post('some_data', TRUE);

Comment: @ZakiPathan still not working..if you can tell me where exactly I am going wrong

Comment: @Sallu According to me everything is fine. I also don't know where the problem is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have look below your code, just I added one line queue.getCache().clear(); That will work.

```
public void setRegistereponse(Registereponse registereponse) {
    this.registereponse = registereponse;
}

private Registereponse registereponse;

public interface Registereponse {
    void onRegsiterReposne(JSONObject object);
}

public void register(JSONObject jsonObject) {


    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, Services.REGISTER_URL, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        Log.e("Json response", "" + response);
                        boolean b = response.getBoolean("success");

                        if (registereponse != null) {
                            registereponse.onRegsiterReposne(response);

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error ", "" + error);
                }
            }
    );
    queue.getCache().clear();
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: queue.getCache().remove(Services.REGISTER_URL); Thanks a ton, this helped me!

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution for it. It worked for me using Async task, but still didn't understand why the error came when I am using Volley.

Comment: there might be an issue of volley cache, clear cache every time when API execution was done. you can do via getRequestCache.getCache().removeKey(keyname). find full description here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464610/how-to-clear-the-volley-cache-automatically

Comment: @HiteshDhamshaniya where should I write this line and how?

Comment: Can you please send your code snapshot, it would be great to understand