# Getting Infinite Loop when starting intent inside onCreate()

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I am new to Android and have come across a problem while implementing it. 
I'm trying to navigate the user to the MainActivity.java activity if the user has already logged in and if the user hasn't logged in then it will have navigate to the LoginActivity.java.

This is the code inside onCreate() method of my MainActivity.java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    sponsorApi = retrofit.create(SponsorInterface.class);

    if (prefs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        user = prefs.getString(Constants.USER, "Username");
        Call<Sponsor> sponsorRequest = sponsorApi.getSponsor(user);
        sponsorRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Sponsor>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Sponsor> call, Response<Sponsor> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                final Sponsor sponsor = response.body();
                name.setText(sponsor.getName());
                Log.d("SponsorDetails Activity", "onResponse: " + statusCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Sponsor> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please login to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

When I run the app, it works but the Activity runs into infinite loop and I don't know what is causing the loop.

**Update1: Debugger**
[image]
PS: SponsorDetails.java in image is MainActivity.java of the question.

**Update2: Removing Intent of MainActivity**
As suggested in the comments I removed

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

But still I am getting the infinite loop in onResponse() method. Yes, after removing the code, I uninstalled the app from emulator and re-ran the app from IDE.

Update 3: onStart() method

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (prefs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please login to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a Debugger?

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class)` - Why would you want to start the `Activity` you're already in again?

Comment: Why : `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42802526/7676750

Comment: I have done the same. @Sallu

Comment: @AnjanaSharma Inside `onCreate` method, check the login `token`. If `token` is available, then navigate, go to  `YourActivity`, otherwise make a login api call or goto login.

Comment: Do you have any other functions in your `MainActivity` like `onStart()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `onStart()` with this

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!prefs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please login to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the **`MainActivity`** **recursively** in if condition,
So when the condition is true MainActivity gets called again and again.

remove two lines

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

or change the activity name you want to go to in if condition.

Comment: I removed the lines but I'm still getting the infinite loop. Thank you for your reply. And now Emulator is also not responding.

Comment: First Restart Emulator, and then try to Re-Run your app from your IDE.

Comment: Yes, I restarted emulator, uninstalled the app and then re-ran the app again from IDE, but the problem still exists.

Comment: can you update the error log (Debugger) and the onCreate()?, It will help to identify error.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your main activity keeps starting itself, and these are the two lines of code causing it. Just remove them.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not updating the logged in status in preferences

Update the status like below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    sponsorApi = retrofit.create(SponsorInterface.class);

    if (prefs.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        user = prefs.getString(Constants.USER, "Username");
        Call<Sponsor> sponsorRequest = sponsorApi.getSponsor(user);
        sponsorRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Sponsor>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Sponsor> call, Response<Sponsor> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                final Sponsor sponsor = response.body();
                name.setText(sponsor.getName());
                Log.d("SponsorDetails Activity", "onResponse: " + statusCode);

                // update the IS_LOGGED_IN status as true
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                editor.putString(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN ,true);
                editor.commit();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Sponsor> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "onFailure: " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });

    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please login to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Please have a try . This will solve your problem